# I18n Polymorphic Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was using [**this**](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association-revised) as a guide for implementing polymorphic association. However, my app is localized and I get an error:

> uninitialized constant En

when I try to go to

> /en/article/1/comments/new

```
  def load_commentable
    resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1, 2]
    @commentable = resource.singularize.classify.constantize.find(id)
  end
```